# .load() with animated .gif while waiting for results

Tags: jquery, load, gif

I am using jquery .load() method to load results of a search within a div like so (dumbed down version)

```
$('#resultscontainer').load("results.php", {data: data});
```

The end result will require more data to be sent and a potential waiting time for the results to be loaded into the div. Is it possible to have an animated gif (like a spinning icon) show within the div "resultscontainer" while it is processing the data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sup livinzlife

yea ofc there is special events in jquery for this :D

```
$("#loading").ajaxStart(function(){
  $(this).show();
});

$("#loading").ajaxStop(function(){
  $(this).hide();
});
```

where #loading is your gif for example: http://www.ajaxload.info/

Comment: Thats a great resource thanks so much! I would just put the above in the same function that calls my load right? So it would be my line in my original post, and then those two'

Comment: the event triggers on all ajax cals so just put it by it self its not cupled with anny thing else